# Problem to parse data XML receive from python socket recv()

Tags: python, xml, sockets, unicode

I created a TCP socket in Python to receive events from my central station Vesta.

The answer I am waiting for is this:

[image: Example to receive]

So far, I've tried a lot of things, and at best, I can get this back with the following code:

```py
server_address = ('xxxxxxx', 1234)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
connection, client_address = sock.accept()    
    
while 1:
  try:    
    chunk = connection.recv(1024)
    decoded_data = chunk.decode(encoding='utf-8')
    for x in decoded_data:
      print(x)
```

Here is the output:

```
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : <
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : ?
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : x
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : m
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : l
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG :
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : v
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : e
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : r
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : s
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : i
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : o
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : n
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : =
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 1
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : .
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 0
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : ?
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : >
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG :
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG :
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : <
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : P
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : a
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : c
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : k
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : e
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : t
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG :
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : I
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : D
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : =
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : T
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : E
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : S
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : T
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : I
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : D
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG :
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : C
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : a
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : l
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : l
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : e
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : r
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : I
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : d
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : =
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 1
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 2
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 7
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 0
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 3
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 8
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 2
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 6
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 9
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 8
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 2
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : 8
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]DEBUG : "
etc etc
[2022-09-01 15:55:27]ERROR : Fatal error : [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

If I don't do the `for`, and just try `print(decoded_data)`, then I get a fast or improbable text.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting with backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

## Process packets in layers

Network and socket programming requires always thinking of the network communcation in layers.

**Packet Data Layers**

1. TCP stream
2. STX/ETX packet
3. UTF8 string
4. XML document

The current problem to your approach is that you are jumping straight from TCP segments to a UTF8 string. But there is no guarantee that the bytes you receive form a proper and complete UTF8 string. (If you stick to characters that are encoded in single-bytes, you are good, but not in general)

##### An approach for processing packets:

1. append data from connection into a buffer
2. check buffer for a full packet with STX/ETX delimiters
3. pull full packet out of buffer and remove STX/ETX characters
4. decode packet data to UTF8 string
5. parse string as an xml document

##### How does this cause bad file descriptor?

If you don't respect the data layers in socket programming, debugging is like constantly chasing your tail. Rewrite the packet processing code with these layers first and then debug.

##### Debugging steps for socket coding

- start debugging if you can with the server and client on your development machine to find any logic bugs
- then debug with the server and client on the same local network to find segmentation, and nagle-like bugs
- then debug with a server and client across the internet to handle disconnection/reconnection, varying bandwidth issues, latency, and jitter.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with network logic, and your explanations will already help me a lot